# IDL for loop overwrites data

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have a problem with my for-loops in IDL.

```
for sl=0,2 do begin  ; number of hours
 for t=90,90 do begin   ; timesteps each hour
  for rad_num = 0, 3 do begin   ; number of radars
   for ibin = 0, 333 do begin   ; distance to radar
     for iray = 0, 359 do begin   ; angle

       if finite(input(ibin,iray,rad_num)) eq 1 then begin
        bin = bin_index(ibin,iray,rad_num)
        ray = ray_index(ibin,iray,rad_num)  ; necessary because of different grids 

        array(sl,t,ray,bin)=array(sl,t,ray,bin)+ input(ibin,iray,rad_num)
        array_N(sl,t,ray,bin) = array_N(sl,t,ray,bin) + 1. 
       endif
      endfor
     endfor
    endfor
   endfor
  endfor

array = array / array_N
```

When I stopped the program after the first sl-loop-step, I get the following:

```
 print, array[0,90,315,49]
     44.0.673
```

But when I don't stop the program, I get this:

```
 print, array[0,90,315,49]
    -NaN
```

It seems, that my program overwrites the data of the previous loop-step. When I make a scatter-plot, I also have the points of the last loop-step only...

Do you see my mistake? 
Thanks a lot!
kiki

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign to `dwd` in the code you show (and the code won't compile as-is because of the enddo's -- I assume you had to rewrite the code instead of copy-and-past for some reason?).

Comment: So there are multiple values of `ibin`/`iray`/`ray_num`, that have the same values in `bin` and `ray`?

Comment: Displaying the data gives me that the plot program gets the same as the main program...

Comment: I'm not sure you understand: multiple values of `ibin`/`iray`/`ray_num` having then same values of `bin` and `ray` is why you are overwriting.